# CharSeT.Ansi does not contain defination for ansi

Tags: c#, character-encoding, marshalling

In C# i am trying to add some additional info like

```
[DllImport("\\SD Card\\ISAPI1.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

but build process giving error

```
Error   1   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet' does not contain a definition for 'Ansi'
```

and the same error "does not contain a defination" i am receiving with

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(intPtr);
```

i am creating a c# application for WinCE 6.0

Comment: So does that mean you're targeting the Compact Framework? It would be worth stating that explicitly - I'm not entirely surprised at members being missing in the CF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compact framework does not support ANSI at all. Hence those parts of the framework relating to ANSI do not exist.

You should use Unicode on the compact framework. I mean, you should use Unicode everywhere, but you get no choice on compact!