# C++ return Array of struct containing string member to c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, dllimport

I need to return array of struct to c# from c++ DLL in Wince 7.

C++ code

```
struct AvailableNetworkList
{
   char strProfileName[7];
   ULONG WLanSignalQuality;
};

BOOL GetAvailableNetworkLists(OUT AvailableNetworkList** data,OUT int *length)
{
      AvailableNetworkList availableNetwork;
      AvailableNetworkList *availableNetworkList = new AvailableNetworkList[pList->dwNumberOfItems];

      for(DWORD i=0;i<pList->dwNumberOfItems;i++)
      {
         availableNetwork.WLanSignalQuality=pList->Network[i].wlanSignalQuality;
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[0] = 'a';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[1] = 'b';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[2] = 'c';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[3] = 'd';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[4] = 'e';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[5] = 'f';
         availableNetwork.strProfileName[6] = 'g';
         availableNetworkList[i] = availableNetwork;

      }
      *length=pList->dwNumberOfItems;
      *data = availableNetworkList;
      return true;
};
```

c# code

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode), Serializable]
    unsafe struct AvailableNetworkList
    {
        public uint WLanSignalQuality;
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)]
        public string strProfileName;
    }

    [DllImport("WLANWRAPPER.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetAvailableNetworkLists(out IntPtr arrayPtr, out int size);
```

Code to call api and sync data with c# structure

```
            IntPtr resultPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            int size = 0;
            bool result2 = GetAvailableNetworkLists(out resultPtr, out size);

            var dataEntrySize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(AvailableNetworkList));
            var availableNetworkList = new AvailableNetworkList[size];
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                var cur = (AvailableNetworkList)Marshal.PtrToStructure(resultPtr, typeof(AvailableNetworkList));
                availableNetworkList[i] = cur;
                resultPtr = new IntPtr(resultPtr.ToInt32() + dataEntrySize);
            }
```

Here everything is working fine .only problem is string value(strProfileName) in struct is set as "abcdefg" in c++ and when it came to c# ,the value is not in readable format as shown in below image.Other integer value is correct.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your string and signal quality struct member positions are reversed in your C# array.

Comment: CharSet.Unicode does not match the `char` used in the native code.  You also have a memory leak, no option to call `delete`

Comment: May I know the best approach to get the string value stored in WCHAR[256] to c# using struct

Comment: @Ron Beyer I rearranged the position. Still no luck

Comment: @Hans Passant I saw in one thread it should be CharSet.Ansi instead Unicode,but the compact framework does not support ANSI at all.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007610/charset-ansi-does-not-contain-defination-for-ansi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa